# Uneven UV Maps from Simple Unfold

Tags: modeling, uv

I recently noticed that unfold in blender doesn't always produce straight UVs. Here's an example as I'm working on some pipes. I have a basic cylinder with the ends deleted. One seam runs down the back of the cylinder. Coming from maya, I'd expect this to unfold perfectly straight. In blender, the UVs start straight on the left half and drift away from the edge of 0-1 space as it moves to the center. I ensured scale and everything was applied, using both angle based and conformal produces uneven seams (though in this example angle based is much more noticeable.) I just ended up straightening the uvs and pinning the corners so when I unfold them they're even, but I would expect the unfold algorithm to unfold that straight, no? Just makes it a little more tedious when working on a modular set to get things to match. Not sure if anyone else had this issue or if I'm missing something.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about with "UVs start straight on the left half and drift away from the edge of 0-1 space as it moves to the center". I don't feel like your image is illustrating the issue you're describing.

Comment: If you look at the top and bottom of the uv'd cylinder, the vertices I'd expect would be straight horizontally, but if you look at the top left most vertex, it lines up right with the grid, as you move to the top right vertext you see the vertices begin to move downwards. I'd expect that to unfold evenly.

Comment: Are you sure the verts on top and bottom are actually 100% level? Try selecting em and S>Z>0 on both ends and then see what happens.